# Finding domain, range, and level curves of $f(x,y)=\arcsin(6y-5x)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I will like it if someone helps me out and also checks my work for me for this equation:

$f(x,y)=\arcsin(6y-5x)$

**Domain**

$-1\leq6y-5x\leq1$

$y\geq\frac{5x}{6}-\frac{1}{6}$ and $y\leq\frac{5x}{6}+\frac{1}{6}$

I think the shape of the domain is a region bounded by two lines.

**Range**

I have no clue how to find the range. I know the range of arcsin is [$\frac{−π} {2}$ , $\frac{π}{2}$].

**Level Curves**

Not very good at this either haha. This is what I did:

$\arcsin(6y-5k)=k$

$6y-5x=\sin k$

I did some test points:

$k=0$: $y=\frac{5}{6}x + 0$

$k=1$: $y=\frac{5}{6}x+\frac{\sin1}{6}$

$k=2:$ $y=\frac{5}{6}x+\frac{\sin2}{6}$

I think that these are unequal parallel lines because $\frac{\sin1}{6}-0 = 0.14$ and $\frac{\sin2}{6}-\frac{\sin1}{6} = 0.011$.

**Boundary of Domain**

I think the boundary is two lines

**Open set, closed set, neither, or both for Domain**

I think the domain is a closed set.

**Is domain bounded or unbounded**

I think the domain is bounded.

I will really appreciate if you helped me on this problem with the range and check my answers and tell me what I did wrong. I feel like I am not very good at these (I take so long to do them).

Thank you, and you might see similar questions like these in the future.

Comment: For the range, let's look at it from this point of view instead of the work you did for a moment. Suppose $x_0 \in [-1,1]$. The question we can ask to find the range is is there a pair $(x_1,y_1) \in \mathrm{domain}(f)$ so that $6y_1 - 5x_1 = x_0$? If so, then the range of $f$ must be $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$. I haven't plotted the domain as you did aobve but i'm sure you'll find your answer using this approach (though there can be many).

Comment: @MathNewbie sorry I don't understand your approach. I know that the range should be -pi/2,pi/2, but I don't get your logic.

Comment: I'm saying for instance if $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is in the range of $f$, then we can find $(x_1,y_1)$ in the domain of $f$ so that $6y_1-5x_1 = 1$.

Comment: Following the example I mentioned above, take any point on the line $y = \frac{5x}{6} + \frac{1}{6}$, you will see that $f$ will map those points to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: @MathNewbie should I be using = or <=? I plugged in y<=$\frac{5(0)}{6}$+$\frac(1}{6}$ and I got y<=$\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: for your domain, $\leq$ is correct. I guess if you mean what I wrote above, perhaps my notation may be a bit confusing. I should write some lines $y_1 = \frac{5x}{6} + \frac{1}{6}$. Hopefully that clarifies your question.

Comment: @MathNewbie No I still don't understand how to find the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain of $f$ consists of lines of the form $y_k = \frac{5x}{6} + k$, where $k \in [-\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6}]$, so since $f(x,\frac{5x}{6}+k) = \sin^{-1}(6(\frac{5x}{6}+k) - 5x)) = \sin^{-1}(5x + 6k - 5x) = \sin^{-1}(6k)$. As $k$ ranges from $\frac{-1}{6}$ to $\frac{1}{6}$, the value $6k$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$. You should verify this. So the range of $f$ is $[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Comment: where did u get the 6 from to multiply?

Comment: Remember that $f(x,y) = \sin^{-1}(6y-5x)$

Comment: also can u explain why the domain is unbounded and not bounded?

Comment: Your boundary of domain is correct and it is a closed set. It is unbounded though. As far as sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can think of bounded sets in this way. If you can draw a circle (though it doesn't have to be a circle) around the set, it is bounded. But since the domain which consists of many lines extend infinitely in each direction, the set is unbounded.

Comment: oh ya that makes sense!! Thank u!

Comment: You're welcome :)